# Adding Days to a date returned through sqlsrv_fetch_array in PHP

Tags: php, date-format, sqlsrv

Initially when i was using php_msssql extension the following line was working

```
$test2_date = date('d-M-y', strtotime( "".$res["test_date"]." +".$noofdays." days" ));
```

`$res` is array.

Then i changed to `php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9` extension due to which the above line was not working because "date" doesn't work in this extension so i used "date_format" which works in sqlsrv. My code line was like shown below

```
$test2_date = date_format(strtotime( "".$res["test_date"]." +".$noofdays." days" ), 'd-M-y');
```

but the strtotime is not working and hence i get the below error:-

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted
>   to string.

what should i use to add days to the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[date_format](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp) take date object as first parameter. So need to create date object with [date_create](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp) first. Code should be:

```
$date = date_create($res["test_date"]);
date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string(" +" . $noofdays . " days"));
echo date_format($date, "d-M-y");
```

**UPDATE:**
If you have date object already then `date_create` step can be skipped and code will be like:

```
date_add($res["test_date"], date_interval_create_from_date_string(" +" . $noofdays . " days"));
echo date_format($date, "d-M-y");
```

Comment: date_create() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: date_add() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given - two errors

Comment: What is value in `$res["test_date"]` ? It must be a date string. If it is not a date string, then you need to check it first before passing to `date_create`.

Comment: not able to echo the value as it gives "Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string " error but in database the value is like this "2018-02-28 15:56:54.000".

Comment: Errors are gone but the date is getting printed as it is. The noofdays are not getting added.

Comment: I've just tried with your given date `2018-02-28 15:56:54.000`, adding `+10 days` and it printed `10-Mar-18`. Can you try adding `+10 days` instead of `$noofdays` once ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174003/discussion-between-japu-soft-dev-and-lovepreet-singh).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve date and time types (datetime, date, time, datetime2, and datetimeoffset) as strings, you have following options:

Set connection option `ReturnDatesAsStrings` to `false` and format returned date field value. This is by default.

```
$server = 'server\instance,port';
$cinfo = array(
    "ReturnDatesAsStrings"=>false,
    "Database"=>'database',
    "UID"=>"user",
    "PWD"=>"password"
);
...
$test2_date = date_format(date_add($res["test_date"], date_interval_create_from_date_string($noofdays." days")), 'd-M-y')
...
```

Set connection option `ReturnDatesAsStrings` to `true`.

```
$server = 'server\instance,port';
$cinfo = array(
    "ReturnDatesAsStrings"=>true,
    "Database"=>'database',
    "UID"=>"user",
    "PWD"=>"password"
);
...
$test2_date = date_format(date_add(date_create($res["test_date"]), date_interval_create_from_date_string($noofdays." days")), 'd-M-y')
...
```

Additional information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).